# mypy: how to ignore specified files (not talking about how to ignore errors)

Tags: python, mypy

I want to let mypy ignore a specified file. I'm **not talking about just ignoring error** (which already answered in many places), rather I want mypy to completely ignore specified files.

When applying mypy to jax library, mypy somehow hangs. For example, let's say there is a file named `main.py` with only single file

```py
import jax
```

Mypy somehow takes really long time (over 5 minuites) when applying `main.py` with the following log (abbreviated). Thus I want let mypy ignore specific file.

```
h-ishida@stone-jsk:/tmp/test$ mypy -v main.py 
LOG:  Could not load plugins snapshot: @plugins_snapshot.json

LOG:  Mypy Version:           0.991
LOG:  Config File:            Default
LOG:  Configured Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
LOG:  Current Executable:     /usr/bin/python3
LOG:  Cache Dir:              .mypy_cache
LOG:  Compiled:               True
LOG:  Exclude:                []
LOG:  Found source:           BuildSource(path='main.py', module='main', has_text=False, base_dir='/tmp/test', followed=False)
LOG:  Could not load cache for main: main.meta.json
LOG:  Metadata not found for main
LOG:  Parsing main.py (main)
LOG:  Could not load cache for jax: jax/__init__.meta.json
LOG:  Metadata not found for jax
LOG:  Parsing /home/h-ishida/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/__init__.py (jax)
LOG:  Metadata fresh for builtins: file /home/h-ishida/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mypy/typeshed/stdlib/builtins.pyi
LOG:  Metadata fresh for jax._src.cloud_tpu_init: file /home/h-ishida/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/cloud_tpu_init.py
LOG:  Could not load cache for jax._src.basearray: jax/_src/basearray.meta.json
LOG:  Metadata not found for jax._src.basearray
...
LOG:  Found 163 SCCs; largest has 196 nodes
LOG:  Processing 161 queued fresh SCCs
LOG:  Processing SCC of size 196 (jax.scipy jax._src.lib jax._src.config jax.experimental.x64_context jax._src.iree jax.config jax._src.pretty_printer jax._src.util jax.util jax._src.lax.stack jax._src.state.types jax._src.lax.svd jax._src.nn.initializers jax._src.lax.qdwh jax._src.debugger.web_debugger jax._src.debugger.colab_debugger jax._src.debugger.cli_debugger jax._src.debugger.core jax._src.clusters.cloud_tpu_cluster jax._src.clusters.slurm_cluster jax._src.clusters jax._src.lax.utils jax._src.profiler jax._src.ops.scatter jax._src.numpy.vectorize jax._src.lax.ann jax._src.lax.other jax._src.errors jax._src.abstract_arrays jax._src.traceback_util jax._src.source_info_util jax._src.callback jax._src.lib.xla_bridge jax._src.sharding jax.lib jax._src.tree_util jax._src.environment_info jax._src.lax.eigh jax._src.lib.mlir.dialects jax.lib.xla_bridge jax._src.stages jax.nn.initializers jax._src.debugger jax._src.distributed jax._src.api_util jax.tree_util jax.profiler jax.ops jax.errors jax._src.typing jax._src.array jax._src.basearray jax._src.state.primitives jax._src.numpy.ndarray jax._src.custom_transpose jax._src.ad_checkpoint jax._src.lax.convolution jax._src.lax.slicing jax._src.debugging jax.linear_util jax.interpreters.mlir jax._src.dtypes jax._src.dispatch jax._src.device_array jax.stages jax.distributed jax.api_util jax.core jax._src.state.discharge jax._src.lax.control_flow.common jax._src.numpy.util jax._src.ad_util jax._src.lax.parallel jax.custom_transpose jax.ad_checkpoint jax.interpreters.pxla jax.interpreters.xla jax.interpreters.partial_eval jax.dtypes jax.debug jax.abstract_arrays jax._src.state jax._src.third_party.numpy.linalg jax._src.numpy.fft jax._src.lax.control_flow.solves jax._src.lax.control_flow.conditionals jax._src.numpy.reductions jax._src.numpy.index_tricks jax.interpreters.batching jax.interpreters.ad jax.sharding jax._src.custom_derivatives jax._src.custom_batching jax.numpy.fft jax._src.lax.lax jax._src.lax.linalg jax.custom_derivatives jax.custom_batching jax.lax.linalg jax._src.api jax.experimental.global_device_array jax._src.prng jax._src.numpy.ufuncs jax._src.lax.fft jax jax._src.numpy.linalg jax._src.lax.control_flow.loops jax.experimental.maps jax._src.lax.windowed_reductions jax._src.image.scale jax._src.numpy.lax_numpy jax.experimental.pjit jax._src.ops.special jax.numpy.linalg jax._src.numpy.setops jax._src.numpy.polynomial jax._src.lax.control_flow jax.image jax._src.random jax._src.nn.functions jax.numpy jax.lax jax.random jax.nn jax._src.dlpack jax.experimental.compilation_cache.compilation_cache jax.experimental jax.interpreters jax._src.lax jax.dlpack jax._src.scipy.cluster.vq jax._src.scipy.stats.gennorm jax._src.scipy.stats.chi2 jax._src.scipy.stats.uniform jax._src.scipy.stats.t jax._src.scipy.stats.pareto jax._src.scipy.stats.multivariate_normal jax._src.scipy.stats.laplace jax._src.scipy.stats.expon jax._src.scipy.stats.cauchy jax._src.third_party.scipy.betaln jax._src.scipy.sparse.linalg jax._src.third_party.scipy.signal_helper jax._src.scipy.fft jax._src.scipy.stats._core jax._src.scipy.ndimage jax._src.scipy.linalg jax._src.third_party.scipy.interpolate jax.scipy.cluster.vq jax.scipy.stats.gennorm jax.scipy.stats.chi2 jax.scipy.stats.uniform jax.scipy.stats.t jax.scipy.stats.pareto jax.scipy.stats.multivariate_normal jax.scipy.stats.laplace jax.scipy.stats.expon jax.scipy.stats.cauchy jax._src.scipy.special jax.scipy.sparse.linalg jax._src.scipy.signal jax._src.third_party.scipy.linalg jax.scipy.fft jax.scipy.ndimage jax.scipy.interpolate jax._src.scipy.stats.betabinom jax._src.scipy.stats.nbinom jax._src.scipy.stats.multinomial jax.scipy.cluster jax.scipy.special jax.scipy.sparse jax.scipy.signal jax.scipy.linalg jax._src.scipy.stats.poisson jax._src.scipy.stats.norm jax._src.scipy.stats.logistic jax._src.scipy.stats.geom jax._src.scipy.stats.gamma jax._src.scipy.stats.dirichlet jax._src.scipy.stats.beta jax._src.scipy.stats.bernoulli jax.scipy.stats.betabinom jax.scipy.stats.nbinom jax.scipy.stats.multinomial jax._src.scipy.stats.kde jax._src.scipy.stats.truncnorm jax.scipy.stats.poisson jax.scipy.stats.norm jax.scipy.stats.logistic jax.scipy.stats.geom jax.scipy.stats.gamma jax.scipy.stats.dirichlet jax.scipy.stats.beta jax.scipy.stats.bernoulli jax.scipy.stats.truncnorm jax.scipy.stats) as inherently stale
```

Comment: Wow, it looks like a major trouble. I'd really advice to open a `mypy` issue: hangs and internal errors are very important.

Comment: @SUTerliakov sorry, I found it was not hanging. After waiting for 5 minutes, it completed.

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore a file"? I understand that you want to bypass the time consuming operation, but how do you expect to use the import if it doesn't complete?

Comment: doing `import jax` in python side is quite fast, so I can normally use that file (module). but mypy seems to take really long time to analyzing the module. @MadPhysicist

Comment: Does it do that every time, or just on the first run?

Comment: Might `Could not load plugins snapshot: @plugins_snapshot.json` be an issue?